# Any better software alternative for mysqldump

Tags: windows, linux, database, mysql

`mysqldump` does not have some simple and really useful options. e.g. its not possible to dump only views, or is not possible to disable version-comments (`/*!40101 /*`). Is there any even a little better alternative?

Comment: That question is better fit on our [DBA sister site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). Hints: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a single table (corresponding alternatives for views, procedures, etc. exist, e.g. `SHOW CREATE VIEW`), use *phpMyAdmin* to export a single table (structure and/or data), or use the tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to construct the DDL,  [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+ddl+extract). If you're looking for a software product to assist you, please [edit] your question and specify that (plus include your corresponding requirements concerning e.g. features, OS, etc.).